# Invertibility of sequence of symmetric square matrices with fixed rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, generalized-inverse

We have  $X=
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & a & b \\
 a & h & c\\
 b & c & h \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 $, $X$ (square, symmetric and at least one element of the diagonal is $1$ and $-1<h<1$ ), assume a sequence of matrices $X_n=
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & a_n & b_n \\
 a_n & h_n & c_n\\
 b_n & c_n & h_n \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 $, where Rank(X_n)=Rank(X). Does that implies that $X$ is invertible? if $X$ is not invertible can the generalized inverse of $X$ be
$X^{+}=
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & g_{12} & g_{13} \\
 g_{14} & g_{15} & g_{16}\\
 g_{17} & g_{18} & g_{19} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 $
or the zero element can never happen given the structure of $X$ (square, symmetric and at least one element of the diagonal is 1 and $-1<h<1$)??

Comment: What is A, the limit of $X_n$? If so, how can you assume Rank(X_n)=Rank(A) for all n?

Comment: @Paul sorry that was a typo, now it is fixed to Rank(X).. this assumption I need to guarantee the continuity of the generalized inverse of the $X$.. I need to see if this assumption is valid for this specific matrix structure it would imply invertibility or not necessary

Comment: For your first question, consider the case where $X_n=X$ for every $n$. Does this imply that $X$ is invertible?